# Solidity upgrading code from 0.5.17 to 0.8.14

Tags: solidity

everyone.
I am studying about smart contract developing by solidity.
In tutorial, I found this code made by solidity version 0.5.17.

```
function step() public;
```

This work for version 0.5.17 but 0.8.14.
How can I change this code to work on version 0.8.14?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions without implementation must be marked virtual.

```
function step() public virtual;
```

Just as an advice, in solidity it is not recommended to use codes built in previous versions without a deep study because they can present serious vulnerabilities.